# error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl

Tags: python

How can I solve this?

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried installing the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python3-pip
sudo pip install lxml
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `-lfoo` fails, look for packages that provide `libfoo.so`. [`libssl.so`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libssl.so&searchon=contents) and [`libcrypto.so`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libcrypto.so&searchon=contents) are provided by `libssl-dev`. So, install `libssl-dev`.

Comment: I faced this error (for lssl & lcrypto) while installing mysqlclient on Ubuntu 18.04 with python3.6. Installing libssl-dev worked perfectly!

Comment: I am wandering why it was able to work previously in the same environment (using docker container with same requirements.txt file and apt install commands). 
May it depend on python3 version which seems has been changed (for Ubuntu 18.04) from 3.6.8 to 3.6.9 ?